# Minigal Nano 0.3.6 thumbnails not generating

Tags: php, gallery, thumbnails

I am using minigal nano 0.3.6, I put my images in the photo directory. The thumbnails are not being generated. But when I click the broken images or thumbnail the image itself opens in lightbox just fine. Following is the code to generate thumbnails:

This script and included files are subject to licensing from Creative Commons (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)
You may use, edit and redistribute this script, as long as you pay tribute to the original author by NOT removing the linkback to www.minigal.dk ("Powered by MiniGal Nano x.x.x")

MiniGal Nano is created by Thomas Rybak

Copyright 2010 by Thomas Rybak
Support: www.minigal.dk
Community: www.minigal.dk/forum

Please enjoy this free script!

USAGE EXAMPLE:
File: createthumb.php
Example: 
*/
//  error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (preg_match("/.jpg$|.jpeg$/i", $_GET['filename'])) header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
if (preg_match("/.gif$/i", $_GET['filename'])) header('Content-type: image/gif');
if (preg_match("/.png$/i", $_GET['filename'])) header('Content-type: image/png');

```
// Display error image if file isn't found
if (!is_file($_GET['filename'])) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $errorimage = ImageCreateFromJPEG('images/questionmark.jpg');
    ImageJPEG($errorimage,null,90);
}

// Display error image if file exists, but can't be opened
if (substr(decoct(fileperms($_GET['filename'])), -1, strlen(fileperms($_GET['filename']))) < 4 OR substr(decoct(fileperms($_GET['filename'])), -3,1) < 4) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $errorimage = ImageCreateFromJPEG('images/cannotopen.jpg');
    ImageJPEG($errorimage,null,90);
}

// Define variables
$target = "";
$xoord = 0;
$yoord = 0;

if ($_GET['size'] == "") $_GET['size'] = 120; //
   $imgsize = GetImageSize($_GET['filename']);
   $width = $imgsize[0];
   $height = $imgsize[1];
  if ($width > $height) { // If the width is greater than the height it’s a horizontal picture
    $xoord = ceil(($width-$height)/2);
    $width = $height;      // Then we read a square frame that  equals the width
  } else {
    $yoord = ceil(($height-$width)/2);
    $height = $width;
  }

// Rotate JPG pictures
if (preg_match("/.jpg$|.jpeg$/i", $_GET['filename'])) {
    if (function_exists('exif_read_data') && function_exists('imagerotate')) {
        $exif = exif_read_data($_GET['filename']);
        $ort = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
        $degrees = 0;
        switch($ort)
        {
            case 6: // 90 rotate right
                $degrees = 270;
            break;
            case 8:    // 90 rotate left
                $degrees = 90;
            break;
        }
        if ($degrees != 0)  $target = imagerotate($target, $degrees, 0);
    }
}

     $target = ImageCreatetruecolor($_GET['size'],$_GET['size']);
     if (preg_match("/.jpg$/i", $_GET['filename'])) $source = ImageCreateFromJPEG($_GET['filename']);
     if (preg_match("/.gif$/i", $_GET['filename'])) $source = ImageCreateFromGIF($_GET['filename']);
     if (preg_match("/.png$/i", $_GET['filename'])) $source = ImageCreateFromPNG($_GET['filename']);
     imagecopyresampled($target,$source,0,0,$xoord,$yoord,$_GET['size'],$_GET['size'],$width,$height);
     imagedestroy($source);

     if (preg_match("/.jpg$/i", $_GET['filename'])) ImageJPEG($target,null,90);
     if (preg_match("/.gif$/i", $_GET['filename'])) ImageGIF($target,null,90);
     if (preg_match("/.png$/i", $_GET['filename'])) ImageJPEG($target,null,90); // Using ImageJPEG on purpose
     imagedestroy($target);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to the EXIF data contained in your images. I had the same problem (using a Canon camera). Hope this is still of help to you. Just go to the line that reads as follows:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($_GET['filename']);
```

Change it to the following:

```
$exif = @exif_read_data($_GET['filename']);
```

The error-images should disappear and your thumbnails should show up.